# Python math module shows completely wrong results?

Tags: python, math, module, trigonometry

I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

```
from math import *
# triangle Law of Sines test:
a = float(3)
b = float(3)
c = 4.24264

A = float(45)
B = float(45)
C = float(90)

# it should be equal to the diameter of the triangle's 
# ...circumcircle when convert radians to degrees (2.12132) :
print a /sin(A)
print c /sin(C)

# and just test angles :
print degrees( sin( float(45) ) ) # 'SHOULD BE 2.8284'
print degrees( sin( float(90) ) ) # 'SHOULD BE 1'
```

...and the printout:

```
>> 3.52566408941
>> 4.74570003753
>> 48.7531807286
>> 51.2222357231
```

Comment: Side note: Don't ask for *not* downvoting. Consider them as a sign that tells you to improve your post, don't be afraid of them, learn how to improve in such cases.

Comment: `degrees()` converts radians to degrees-- two kinds of angles. Sines and cosines are not angles (their argument is). Check your math. E.g., `sin(radians(90))` is 1; don't convert.

Comment: @Maroun I don't care for constructive downwote, but don't like bold haters.

Comment: @Alex: People are usually too busy to take the time to hate you personally. Usually it's more that your questions sucks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should do the following:

```
sin(radians(90))
```

[`radians`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/math.html) convert the given angle from degrees to *radians*, and since `sin` expects `radians`, now it should print 1 as you expected.

Comment: I had hard time trying to convert apples to oranges. Thanks.